# Xcode iOS simulator fails to install. How can I uninstall?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to install iOS 8.2 and 8.1 simulators but they fail to install
and I end up with with a checkmark as if they're installed.

Can I uninstall them?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing that leads you to believe the install failed?

Comment: I press download, it downloads a little bit, and then just stops. When I press cancel I get the error message claiming it fails to install and then the download process stops and the checkmark appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to "Window -> Devices" to get a list of devices including simulators. To delete a simulator, with select it and hit <kbd>⌫</kbd> or right click it and click "Delete".